# candidate and loop function in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, element, frequency

This function finds the occurrences of the elements in the list, then prints a list of occurrence and the element. The second prints the mode of the list of nondecreasing integers. That is when you write (make-element-freq-list '(1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 5)) it prints '((1 . 2) (2 . 2) (3 . 1) (4 . 2) (5 . 3)). But i cannot understand the candidate'() and loop (why it takes l l?) operation here.  Can anybody help me to understand these please? thanks.

```
#lang racket
(define make-element-freq-list
  (lambda (l)
    (let loop ((l l) (candidate '()) (count 0))
      (cond
        ((null? (cdr l)) (append candidate (list (cons (car l) (+ count 1)))))
        (else
         (if (equal? (car l) (cadr l))
             (loop (cdr l) candidate (+ count 1))
             (loop (cdr l) (append candidate (list (cons (car l) (+ count 1)))) 0 )))))))  
(define mode
  (lambda (l)
    (let loop ((l l) (max-freq (cdar l)) (mode (caar l)))
      (cond
        ((null? l) mode)
        (else
         (if (> max-freq (cdar l))
             (loop (cdr l) max-freq mode)
             (loop (cdr l) (cdar l) (caar l) )))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (make-element-freq-list l)
  (let loop ((l l) (candidate '()) (count 0))
    ...))
```

Is pretty much syntactic sugar for this:

```
(define (make-element-freq-list l)
  (define (loop l candidate count)
    ...)

  (loop l '() 0))
```

So in a named `let` you have the initial values of the first application together with the name it should be bound with. In the let you call it the same way as if it was made with `define` and called.

The name `loop` is just that. A name. You can call it anything you'd like, but `loop` is a naming convention for tail recursive code.

Scheme doesn't have any looping or iterating constructs that isn't just an abstraction (either a procedure or a macro) that ends up iterating with recursive calls.